# XSL conversion from 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a problem converting XSLT 2.0 to XSLT 3.0. I want to use the streaming capability of XSLT 3.0. I am struggling with using the `<xsl:stream>` and `<xsl:mode>` tags as XSLT 3.0 has several restrictions. For using XSLT 3.0 streaming capabilities, following restrictions are faced:

1. “Sibling nodes and ancestor sibling are not reachable”.
2. "You can visit child nodes only once"
3. "You have access only to the current element attributes and namespace declaration"

How can I overcome these restrictions? Can anyone please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">

         <xsl:stream href="SampleInput3_0.xml">
            <xsl:for-each select="copy-of(ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT/ns0:PID)">
               <Patient>
                  <ucfd:Name>
                     <xsl:variable name="varFirst_Name" as="node()" select="ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.2[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]" />
                     <xsl:variable name="varLast_Name" as="node()" select="ns0:XPN.1/ns0:FN.1[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]" />
                     <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="concat(string($varFirst_Name), string(varLast_Name))" />
                  </ucfd:Name>
                  <ucfd:FirstName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  <ucfd:LastName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.1/ns0:FN.1}" />
                  <ucfd:MiddleName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.3[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  <ucfd:Prefix value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.5[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  <ucfd:Suffix value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.4[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  <ucfd:Identification>
                     <ucfd:TaxIdentifier>
                        <ucfd:Type value="{ns0:PID.18/ns0:CX.5[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        <ucfd:Identifier value="{ns0:PID.18/ns0:CX.1}" />
                     </ucfd:TaxIdentifier>
                  </ucfd:Identification>
                  <xsl:for-each select="ns0:PID.11">
                     <ucfd:Address>
                        <xsl:if test="exists(@Type)">
                           <ucfd:Type value="{ns0:XAD.7[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        </xsl:if>
                        <ucfd:City value="{ns0:XAD.3[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        <ucfd:State value="{ns0:XAD.4[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        <ucfd:PostalCode value="{ns0:XAD.5[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        <ucfd:Country value="{ns0:XAD.6[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                        <ucfd:County value="{ns0:XAD.9[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     </ucfd:Address>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                  <ucfd:Contact>
                     <ucfd:Role value="{ns0:PID.13/ns0:XTN.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <ucfd:Type value="{ns0:PID.13/ns0:XTN.3[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <xsl:for-each select="ns0:PID.13">
                        <!--<xsl:variable name="var9_current" as="node()" select="."/>-->
                        <ucfd:CommunicationNumber>
                           <xsl:if test="exists(@Type)">
                              <ucfd:Type>
                                 <xsl:sequence select="()" />
                              </ucfd:Type>
                           </xsl:if>
                           <ucfd:Identifier>
                              <!--<xsl:variable name="var8_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.5[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var7_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.6[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var6_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.7[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var5_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.8[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var4_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.10[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var3_current" as="node()" select="ns0:XTN.11[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(string($var8_current), string($var7_current)), string($var6_current)), string($var5_current)), string($var4_current)), string($var3_current))"/> -->
                           </ucfd:Identifier>
                        </ucfd:CommunicationNumber>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                  </ucfd:Contact>
                  <ucfd:Demographics>
                     <ucfd:BirthDate>
                        <xsl:sequence select="()" />
                     </ucfd:BirthDate>
                     <ucfd:BirthSequenceNumber>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT/ns0:PID/ns0:PID.25">
                           <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="">
                              <xsl:if test="not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))">
                                 <xsl:sequence select="xs:string(xs:integer(string(.)))" />
                              </xsl:if>
                           </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </ucfd:BirthSequenceNumber>
                     <ucfd:DeathDate>
                        <xsl:sequence select="()" />
                     </ucfd:DeathDate>
                     <ucfd:Gender value="ns0:PID.8[not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1'))]" />
                     <ucfd:MaritalStatus value="{ns0:PID.16/ns0:CE_0002.1[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <ucfd:CitizenshipStatus value="{ns0:PID.26[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <ucfd:RaceOrEthnicity>
                        <ucfd:Race value="{ns0:PID.10/ns0:CE_0005.1[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     </ucfd:RaceOrEthnicity>
                     <ucfd:Religion value="{ns0:PID.17/ns0:CE_0006.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  </ucfd:Demographics>
                  <ucfd:Language>
                     <ucfd:LanguageCode value="{ns0:PID.15/ns0:CE_0296.1[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <ucfd:Description value="{ns0:PID.15/ns0:CE_0296.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                     <ucfd:UseIndicator value="{ns0:PID.15/ns0:CE_0296.3[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1')]}" />
                  </ucfd:Language>
               </Patient>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:stream>
      </MemberRecord>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3769767 If there is other private information in that code other than the domains, please point it out. If it absolutely can't appear, we can burn the revisions where it's visible. But removing *all* of the code is not acceptable, because it's relevant to answering the question. As you can see in the answer below, the user anonymized all of the domain names. Is there any other information that should not be displayed?

Comment: Yes there are other confidential information. I masked the domain name earlier in June itself but now I would like the complete xml namespace to be removed if the whole xsl cannot be removed. You just repost the code in the question as I am no longer able to see it and I will edit it so that no confidential information is there. Also, I would like to edit the answers posted by the other user as masking the domain is not enough.

Comment: You can edit a previous revision from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24379136/revisions). Just select which revision you want to start with and click the *edit* button on that revision. Would simply anonymizing all the URLs in the code suffice (i.e. replacing them with "..." to indicate they exist but are not shown)?

Comment: I have removed the URLs from the XSL. I also want to remove the URL's in the answers posted by the other user. Replacing URL's with "..." will also suffice. How can I edit the answers ?

Comment: I've edited the answer for you. Does everything look ok now?

Comment: Hi, Yes everything looks ok now.. Thanks ! Also, can this conversation be hidden as I don't want it to be viewed publically ? I will highly appreciate if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the approach in http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/streaming/burst-mode-streaming so along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="..."
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="..." xmlns:ccfd="..." xmlns:hcfd="..." xmlns:ucf="..." xmlns:ucfd="..."
  exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>

<!-- start with this named template -->
<xsl:template name="main">
  <MemberRecord xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <Patient>
      <xsl:stream href='employees.xml'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT/ns0:PID)"/>
      </xsl:stream>
    </Patient>
  </MemberRecord>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:PID">
  <ucfd:Name value="{...}"/>
  <ucfd:FirstName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1'))]}"/>
  <ucfd:LastName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.1/ns0:FN.1}"/>
  <!-- compute the other elements and attributes here as above -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should show the approach, you will have to add code for the remaining elements like middle name and prefix and so on. I have also tried to simplify the compuation of the attribute `value` in some cases, I think the same can be done for the other cases but I think you should ask that in a different question where you provide details of the XML structure and the values you want to compute, all those nested for-eachs to generate a single `value` attribute seem a bit convoluted.

Also note that I have followed your posted code in creating a single `Patient` element, I would however expected that a `ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT` element is mapped to a `Patient` so more along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="..."
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="..." xmlns:ccfd="..." xmlns:hcfd="..." xmlns:ucf="..." xmlns:ucfd="..."
  exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>

<!-- start with this named template -->
<xsl:template name="main">
  <MemberRecord xsi:schemaLocation="...">

      <xsl:stream href='employees.xml'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT)"/>
      </xsl:stream>
    </Patient>
  </MemberRecord>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT">
  <Patient>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Patient>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:PID">
  <ucfd:Name value="{...}"/>
  <ucfd:FirstName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.2[not(translate(@xsi:nil, 'true ', '1') = '1'))]}"/>
  <ucfd:LastName value="{ns0:PID.5/ns0:XPN.1/ns0:FN.1}"/>
  <!-- compute the other elements and attributes here as above -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin ! It really helped me.. and you are right, ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT element is mapped to a Patient and it contains other child elements also other than PID. I will use the second XSL which you have provided.

Comment: Also, I have pasted the full Patient XSL in my question above. Should I follow the same approach for rest of the elements (Identification, Address, Demographics, Language etc.)also ? Thanks a lot in Advance !!

Comment: As for the streaming, I assume the input has too many `ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT` to build a complete tree of them with traditional XSLT 2.0 processing but a single `ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT` fits into memory fine and the processing only needs to access its child or descendants. So that way with the `<xsl:stream href='employees.xml'><xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT)"/>` the XSLT 3.0 processor will read in a streaming way sequentially step by step any `ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT` element and will then allow us normal XSLT processing on a copy.

Comment: That way you should be able to use any processing with templates or if needed for-each on the child and descendants of the `ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT` elements like the `ns0:PID`, without needing to think about streaming restrictions.

Comment: Thats great ! Just one question. I may sound dumb on this but <xsl:stream href="employees.xml">. Do I need to provide employees.xml file for streaming to work  or its just a dummy file and makes no difference?

Comment: I assume `employees.xml` to be your very large input file you want to process in a streaming way. The code I have written should be called with Saxon by providing an initial template as the starting point, using the command line option `it:main`. I have corrected the XSLT in my answer to have that named template, it should have been that way in the first edit but somehow I forgot that change and simply put the comment in there.

Comment: Got that Martin ! Thanks a lot for your help ! I will build the complete XSL using the guidelines you have provided and will post it here again for your review (if you dont mind :-) ). I am still waiting for my Saxon 9.5 EE 30-day trial license. It should have reached by now but somehow it got delayed.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have created the XSL as per your guidelines and have posted the new XSL in my question above. The <apply-templates> tag did not work for Saxonica 9.5 EE XSLT processor. I got the error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template cannot be cast to com.saxonica.stream.TemplateInversion" and found that this is a bug in Saxonica as explained in the link: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1632

Comment: So, instead I used the for-each loop,  <xsl:for-each select="copy-of(ns0:ORM_O01/ns0:ORM_O01.PATIENT/ns0:PID)"> under the <xsl:stream> tag as shown in my XSL in the question. Is it the correct approach or is there any other alternative for <apply-templates> ... Thanks in Advance !

Comment: In my understanding that bug report relates to Saxon 9.4 only but I can't tell for sure. I am afraid I can't test myself, I think you either need to wait till Michael Kay answers here or you could alternatively post on the Saxon mailing list or the Saxon forum, there you should get a definitive answer. If Saxon does not throw an error on the code you have now I would run with the `-t` option to see whether it really has not built a tree but has processed in streaming mode, then you can be sure you have something that works with the current Saxon release.

Comment: Hi Martin.. Thanks for the suggestion.. I ran the transformation with the -t command and got the following result:
Stylesheet compilation time: 356 milliseconds
Processing file:SampleInput3_0.xml initial template = main
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:SampleInput3_0.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 19 milliseconds
Tree size: 1218 nodes, 994 characters, 266 attributes
Execution time: 81ms
Memory used: 12345960
NamePool contents: 318 entries in 236 chains. 9 URIs

Comment: Does this mean that streaming did not work ? As it has created a tree ?